# "Either way" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

> It's fine either way.
>
> Either way is fine.
>
> I am fine (with) either way.

Are all these constructions usable?

Comment: Sure. Does something make you think that they are not?

Comment: I thought some of them could be outdated or might sound unpleasant to the native ear.